# How to transform a single target file with using React.js JSX transformer?

Tags: reactjs

So, I installed the jsx tool:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html

```
npm install -g react-tools
```

The documentation gives no information about transforming single files. For instance, the only way it's proposed to use the tool is this:

```
jsx --watch src/ build/
```

This would transform ALL files from src/ into build/.

However, I would like to transform a single file only. Is it possible with using the `jsx` tool?

Comment: FYI, react-tools is being deprecated https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compile a single jsx file to js just use:

```
jsx myfile.jsx > myfile.js
```

You can output to a build directory as appropriate

```
jsx myfile.jsx > build/myfile.js
```

Comment: That simple! Strange they don't mention it in the documentation.

Comment: The docs (for react-tools) leave a bit to be desired IMO, I made an educated guess and it worked.

Comment: So, having two .js files residing in the same directory, just one will get compiled by using your method, is this correct?

Comment: The one you target will get compiled and nothing else.